# How to group dataframe datetime by month to make monthly counts of occurrence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, plotly

I have a dataframe of the reasons why a pyament was reloaded with the date that looks like this:

```
>>>df[['Message retour auto.', 'Date du paiement']]

    Message retour auto.                        Date du paiement
0   Transaction non permise à ce porteur        28/07/2021 03:10:00
1   NaN                                         28/07/2021 03:10:00
2   Ne pas honorer                              28/07/2021 03:10:00
3   NaN                                         28/07/2021 03:10:00
4   Provision insuffisante ou crédit dépassé    28/07/2021 03:10:00
... ... ...
3601    Ne pas honorer                          01/01/2021 03:10:00
3602    Ne pas honorer                          01/01/2021 03:10:00
3603    Ne pas honorer                          01/01/2021 03:10:00
3604    Transaction non permise à ce porteur    01/01/2021 03:10:00
3605    Provision insuffisante ou crédit dépassé    01/01/2021 03:10:00
```

I would like to show the sum of each of the reasons per month, so I did:

```
message_names = df['Message retour auto.'].unique()
df = df.groupby(["Date du paiement","Message retour auto."]).size()

import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

temp = df.groupby(["Date du paiement","Message retour auto."]).size()

temp1 = temp.rename('size').reset_index()


message_d = {}

for message in message_names:
  message_d[message] = temp1[temp1["Message retour auto."]==message]

data = []

for message in message_d.keys():
      data.append(go.Bar(name=str(message), 
                         x=message_d[message]['Date du paiement'], 
                         y=message_d[message]['size']))


fig = go.Figure(data=data)

fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
```

But it returns:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

And not only it isn't by day but it's not very nice with the legend on the right that takes too much place...

I tried but have a problem with `df.resample("M")["Message retour auto"]` because it seems to me that it creates dates that do not exist. In effect the last dates of my dataframe are:

```
>>>df_original['Date du paiement'].tail()
Date du paiement
2020-04-05 10:33:00   2020-04-05 10:33:00
2020-04-05 07:19:00   2020-04-05 07:19:00
2020-04-05 03:10:00   2020-04-05 03:10:00
2020-04-05 03:10:00   2020-04-05 03:10:00
2020-04-05 03:10:00   2020-04-05 03:10:00
```

But when I use it:

```
df_original['Date du paiement'] = pd.to_datetime(df_original['Date du paiement'])
df_original.index = df_original['Date du paiement']
df = df_original.resample("M")["Message retour auto."].agg(lambda x: Counter(list(x)))
df = df.to_frame()
df
```

I returns me dates in 01/2020:

```
    Message retour auto.
Date du paiement    
2020-01-31  {'Provision insuffisante ou crédit dépassé': 2...
2020-02-29  {'Provision insuffisante ou crédit dépassé': 8...
2020-03-31  {'Provision insuffisante ou crédit dépassé': 7...
2020-04-30  {'Transaction non permise à ce porteur': 2, 'N...
2020-05-31  {'Ne pas honorer': 36, 'Transaction non permis...
2020-06-30  {'Ne pas honorer': 53, 'Provision insuffisante...
2020-07-31  {'Provision insuffisante ou crédit dépassé': 3...
2020-08-31  {'Ne pas honorer': 61, 'Transaction non permis...
2020-09-30  {'Provision insuffisante ou crédit dépassé': 2...
2020-10-31  {'Transaction non permise à ce porteur': 20, '...
2020-11-30  {'Ne pas honorer': 58, 'Transaction non permis...
2020-12-31  {'Ne pas honorer': 45, 'Provision insuffisante...
2021-01-31  {'Transaction non permise à ce porteur': 49, '...
2021-02-28  {'Ne pas honorer': 46, 'Provision insuffisante...
2021-03-31  {'Ne pas honorer': 47, 'Transaction non permis...
2021-04-30  {'Ne pas honorer': 43, 'Suspicion de fraude': ...
2021-05-31  {'Transaction non permise à ce porteur': 35, '...
2021-06-30  {'Ne pas honorer': 40, 'Conserver la carte': 5...
2021-07-31  {'Ne pas honorer': 42, 'Provision insuffisante...
2021-08-31  {'Transaction non permise à ce porteur': 13, '...
2021-09-30  {'Ne pas honorer': 5, 'Provision insuffisante ...
2021-10-31  {'Ne pas honorer': 9, 'Transaction invalide': ...
2021-11-30  {'Ne pas honorer': 15, 'Transaction non permis...
2021-12-31  {'Ne pas honorer': 8, 'Date de validité de la ..
```

You can see my google colab [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_U96W9KVSL77CtPlWn61dF2GbyMdf44G?usp=sharing).